# Centres of Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Suppose we have a space curve $r(t)=\left(x(t), y(t), z(t)\right)$ and we consider the locus of all centres of curvature of $r$. First, would this be the correct formula? $$r(t) + {1 \over \kappa(t)} N(t)$$ (where $N$ is the normal vector in the TNB-frame and $\kappa$ is curvature). And is there a name for this curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For planar curves, it is called the [*evolute*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) of the curve.

For a discussion of the spatial case, see

> Dmitry Fuchs, [Evolutes and Involutes of Spatial Curves](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.217), 
>   *The American Mathematical Monthly*,
>   Vol. 120, No. 3 (March 2013), pp. 217-231 2013. DOI: [10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.217](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.217)